# eq() method question

Tags: jquery

For example, I have this HTML structure:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a">some text</a></li>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a">some text</a></li>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a">some text</a></li>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a ac_current_a">some text</a></li>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a">some text</a></li>
    <li><a class="ac_list_a">some text</a></li>
</ul>
```

I need to get the next or previous `ac_list_a` from `ac_current_a`.

I have tried to do like this:

```
var all_a = $('.ac_list_a,.ac_current_a').eq('.ac_current_a').next();
```

But it doesn't work.

How would you solve it?

**Update**

That is, of course I can do it the dumb way, by assigning class to all `li` elemnts, then using

```
parents(class).next().find(a.class)
```

But is it possible to do it more dynamic way? Because the structure of HTML could change in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eq` takes an integer index for a function, not a selector.  You can use the `index` function to find that index, however, and then use `eq`.

```
var index = $('.ac_list_a,.ac_current_a').index($('.ac_current_a'));
var all_a = $('.ac_list_a,.ac_current_a').eq(index+1);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would probably use:

```
$('.ac_current_a').parent().next().children()
```

Demo: [jsfiddle.net/dL87J/](http://jsfiddle.net/dL87J/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `eq()`:

```
$('.ac_list_a .ac_current_a').parent().next();
$('.ac_list_a .ac_current_a').parent().prev();
```

Comment: That returns an empty jQuery object, as the link doesn't have any siblings.